# Android new file on sdcard Broadcast event

Tags: android

I want to be notified (via broadcast) when a new file is created on the sdcard in a particular folder.
I can create a service and poll for it, but I would prefer an system event if it exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it. [FileObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html) would do it.